# Transferring purchased apps across phones

Tags: apple-id, data-transfer

I purchased an app on my old iPhone and then upgraded my phone. The problem is that I also changed my Apple ID as I couldn't remember my old login details for the original ID. Now I want to continue using a running training app from my old phone which has stored some personal data which I'd really like to continue using on the new phone. Is there any chance I can do this?

Comment: Does this running app allow you to export the data from the old iPhone and import it into the new one?  Apps, and their data, are usually tied to an Apple ID so changing that means you, most often, will lose the data.  However, some apps allow a separate export/import function.

Comment: Is your question just about transferring the data, or also about transferring the app itself? Also, have you still got the old iPhone? Finally, if possible, can you specify the app in question?

Comment: Thanks for responses. Transferring app and data. Yes I have the old phone. App is 5K runner.

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of the app and asked them if it's possible to export/import the data?  If so, then it might not matter about your Apple ID.